# Restore user db from UNC

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I need to create a job that restores all user databases from UNC to my SQL Server.

1. All the backups, for 3 days, are located in the same folder and I need to restore the last modified backup.
2. What is the right way to do this? Build steps to all databases separately?

I need a suggestion on how to build it.

Comment: Are you restoring to another server?  To the originating server?  If you have access to the server that was backed up, in the msdb database the record of backups is maintaned in the 5 dbo.backup... tables.

Comment: Are you automating this or is it a 1 time thing?

Comment: Also, if you're a fan of powershell, consider using DBATools, it gives you some very easy scripts to automate backups

Answer (score 0):

If you can setup a linked server to the source database server you can simply do a restore from the last backup device containing a full database backup by finding the last backup file like this:

```
Declare @Database sysname = 'a'
Declare @BackupFile NVARCHAR(1024)
select @BackupFile =  bf.physical_device_name from
(select MAX(ISNULL(bs.backup_finish_date, 0)) AS backup_date, 
            bm.physical_device_name   
            FROM SOURCESERVER.master.dbo.sysdatabases AS sd 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN SOURCESERVER.msdb.dbo.backupset AS bs ON sd.name = bs.database_name 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN SOURCESERVER.msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS bm ON bm.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
          where sd.name = @database
          GROUP BY 
            bm.physical_device_name) bf
Declare @RestoreStatement NVARCHAR(1024) = 'Restore database ['+ @Database +'] from disk = N'''+@BackupFile+''' with replace,recovery'
execute SP_EXECUTESQL @RestoreStatement;
```

Now if you only have access to the unc path but not the linked server then the @backupfile becomes like this:.

```
Declare @BackupFile NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @cmdline varchar(2000)
DECLARE @ReturnCode nvarchar(max)
CREATE TABLE #tempTable (cmdShellOutput VARCHAR(500))
SET @cmdline = 'start /B powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoLogo -command "Get-ChildItem -Path ''\\server\Backup'' -Filter ''*.bak'' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name"'
INSERT #tempTable
EXEC @ReturnCode = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmdline
select @BackupFile = (select top 1 cmdShellOutput from #tempTable)
DROP TABLE #tempTable
```